Is it possible to "encrypt" a function?
function createUser(data) {
 var time=Date()
 var newUser=new User(data.username)
 newUser.setCreateDate(time)
 
 var res={result:newUser,duration:Date()-time}
 return res
}

so maybe i'd like to put that on a smart contract, but i don't want the node to have even the slightest clue what's this function is doing however if it's a function, i could use the bandwidth to mix it with some extra side-noise, i.e. the function needs to be "sampled" into a 1000 smaller functions and encrypted or something like that. Does that mean it needs to be rewritten from imperative into functional?
It's probably only possible via obfuscation when run-time mutations are introduced to conceal the control-flow... I mean it's just when the contract is open, everyone can see my code right but it's kind of proprietary so there must be some way to use polynomials like in an encryption algorithm to automatically "encrypt" the function as well... that would be groundbreaking because that would mean that on the blockchain, aws-style lambda compute (homomorphically encrypted) could be performed but the fact that nodes get access to source code now is making the whole thing kind of. useless .

Well, you could encrypt the source of the function.

and how would that be run then without being decrypted. well it could be if you grant nodes access control by some id and store this on the blockchain but that would also have to be encrypted but it's still a good idea yeah thanks although the question is different

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_obfuscation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indistinguishability_obfuscation

@D.W. ok i wanna make a 3d obfuscator (quantum-resistant) where the program's result would only be meaningful the the owner of the transaction since he's got the private key. the entire purpose of the computation is completely hidden from the network. otherwise why would i wanna use web3 anyway it's stupid because everyone can see what i'm computing? that's nuts. the only purpose is private nodes at the moment but if the code is obfuscated... you could even run rinks of distributed computation units where the compute jobs are so scrambled that they can't be put back together.

You are looking for homomorphic encryption. As Wikipedia puts it:

Homomorphic encryption is a form of encryption that allows computations to be performed on encrypted data without first having to decrypt it. The resulting computations are left in an encrypted form which, when decrypted, result in an output that is identical to that produced had the operations been performed on the unencrypted data. Homomorphic encryption can be used for privacy-preserving outsourced storage and computation. This allows data to be encrypted and outsourced to commercial cloud environments for processing, all while encrypted.

So, essentially, the idea is that

You encode data locally and send it encrypted to the untrusted node for computation.
Without decrypting the data, the node runs the (special) code that you provided, computes an encrypted result, and sends it back to you.
You decode the result locally.

Note that in the second step the node has access to your code and it can precisely observe what the code does, but it still cannot tell what got computed, because the data it is operating with is encrypted at all times. Encryption of input and decryption of output only occurs locally in an environment that you trust.
The Wikipedia page has a bunch of references and it also lists libraries that implement homomorphic encryption.

no but i'm asking about encrypting the state machine of the target function not the data. i think i need to change to functional programming to eliminate the locks then encode each function with a reversable transformation. ie homomorphic compute rather than data encryption. so i'm not looking for h.enc as you've suggested and i want that "note" eliminated. im pretty sure it's possible

Functional programming has nothing to do with this. Please think carefully about what homomorphic encryption does: it allows you to compute remotely on a machine that you do not trust., communicating through a public network. This solves the gist of your problem, whreas you are trying to solve the problem in a bad way that isn't going to work. Spies can see precisely what your program is doing, whether it's functional or not.
